# How to add ssl certificate config parameters for AWS RDS MySQL connection for metricbeat

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds, metricbeat

I am trying to configure the AWS RDS metric using metricbeat mysql module.
I have enabled the require_secure_transport ON for aws rds parametergroup
Below is the mysql.yml (/etc/metricbeat/modules.d/mysql.yml)

- module: mysql
  metricsets:
  status
  period: 10s
  hosts: ["tcp(my_rds_endpoint:3306)/"]
  username: my_username
  password: my_password

ERROR: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-12-28T10:58:23.514Z",
"log.origin":{"file.name":"module/wrapper.go","file.line":256},"message":"Error fetching data for metricset mysql.status:Error 3159: Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}

I tried adding below parameters but still same issue.

```
- module: mysql
  metricsets:
  status
  period: 10s
  hosts: ["tcp(my_rds_endpoint:3306)/"]
  username: my_username
  password: my_password
  ssl.enabled: true
  ssl.verification_mode: full
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/opt/ssl/global-bundle.pem"]
  logging.level: debug
```

Note: When i turned of require_secure_transport OFF metricbeat mysql module is working fine
only issue with ssl,
Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong CA Bundle
You have to use a valid CA Bundle for RDS on your client side.

Check this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Section **Viewing the CA for your database** and verify which CA bundle is used by your RDS database.

From Section **Certificate bundles for specific AWS Regions** download the one corresponding to your RDS database Region.

Use the downloaded bundle in your client settings.

Comment: This is **not** a link-only answer. But almost all the relevant details are contained in the link, so it suffers from most of the problems of a link-only answer discussed at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer. Please add relevant details from the link to your answer.

Comment: used both global and region specific certificates, we are still getting the same issue. our aws rds aurora certificate authority is rds-ca-rsa4096-g1.